# Modifying IAP Price Tier and release new ver of app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I want to change price tiers. Example, I have 5 IAP Id , and first of one will be decrease to TIER 3 -> TIER 1 and it will be in my new version of app.

But, current version still uses TIER 3 and if i make a modify price tier  and make a schedule, I really do not know  when it's going to be approve of new version app  by Apple Review Team.

Also Review team will be confused ? if the Price Tier has not change yet due to sync problem  of Price Tier schedule of release  time. If do , they will see my price "tier 3" in ITC but new ver. of app uses "tier 1".

I really got confused about that situation  ? I don't want to add new Tier because  they have same function ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make a new, lower priced, duplicate product in iTunes connect, then embed the new product ID in the new version of your app. Otherwise you could end up with a situation where people using the old version of your app are able to purchase with the new, lower price. You can then think about phasing out the old product when you are happy that enough of your user base has migrated to the newest version of your app?

Comment: I think best solution is yours, but i am scared what if Apple will reject new version of my IAP due to duplication ? If will not problem, i will definitely follow this path ...

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to offer the lower price to the existing users? (Is the price hard-coded for example?) The other option is just to lower the price for all?

Comment: Existing user can also buy in new prices, but the credits which bought before IAP revision, they need to use it. May be i will make promotion for them yet I do not know. And yes, price lists are image (Not jSon object parsing from Apple) that's why i need to release neww app version of modified IAP's ...